Nuxt 3 404 (Not Found) For Exisitng Pages
about:1 GET https://www.sathyamolagoda.me/about 404 (Not Found)

I'm having an issue with my website, built with Nuxt 3 and deployed on Vercel. The page at https://www.sathyamolagoda.me/about returns a 404 (Not Found) error when accessed directly, although it works fine when navigating through Nuxt routes. Google and other third-party tools can't find or access this page. What could be the problem?
Google Live URL :

GtMatrix :

nuxt.config.ts :
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  router: {
    options: {
      scrollBehaviorType: "smooth",
    },
  },
  app: {
    head: {
      charset: "utf-8",
      viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
    },
  },
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/main.css",
    "~/node_modules/highlight.js/styles/night-owl.css",
  ],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  components: [
    {
      path: "~/components/layout-components",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
    {
      path: "~/components/content",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
    {
      path: "~/components/home-page",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
    {
      path: "~/components/about-page",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
    {
      path: "~/components/blog-page",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
    {
      path: "~/components",
      extensions: [".vue"],
    },
  ],
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts",
    "@nuxt/content",
    "@nuxt/image",
    "nuxt-jsonld",
  ],
  googleFonts: {
    families: {},
    download: false,
    overwriting: false,
  },
  build: {
    transpile: ["gsap"],
  },
  image: {
    format: ["webp"],
    imagekit: {
      baseURL: "https://ik.imagekit.io/xxxxx/",
    },
  },
  routeRules: {
    "/**": { prerender: true },
  },
  ssr: true,

  nitro: {
    static: true,
    prerender: {
      routes: [
        "/",
        "/about",
        "/blog"
      ],
      crawlLinks: true,
      concurrency: 12,
    },
  },
  generate: {
    routes: [
      "/",
      "/about",
      "/blog"
    ],
  }
});


I clicked the link you provided and no error occurred. Your CV was displayed correctly. Try clean the cache and hard refresh

How do you build your app? Can you try to preview it locally? Check for some errors in the console. You can also try to host on Netlify. As told before, you can also double-check locally by disabling JS to see if it's coming from the server or not. Btw the components is useless in your config, it's done automatically.

@kissu actually I have hosted this in vercel. and the other thinng if I remove component from config those components will not be rendered. all my other pages got indexed only this page having this issue.
